# Why do I get an error when putting more elements in a row of a bmatrix?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I'm using `bmatrix` to display a simple matrix. Curiously, this does not work with a 1x11 matrix, while it does work with a 1x10 matrix:

This works just fine:

```
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5 & a_6 & a_7 & a_8 & a_9 & a_{10} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
```

while this

```
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5 & a_6 & a_7 & a_8 & a_9 & a_{10} & a_{11}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
```

fails with

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. <recently read> \endtemplate 
l.255 ... & a_5 & a_6 & a_7 & a_8 & a_9 & a_{10} &
                                               a_{11}
```

What does this mean, why does this happen and how can I fix it?

I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) on Ubuntu Trusty·

Comment: Read from my lips: Don't use `$$....$$`

Comment: @egreg: it is indeed a duplicate. I feel very stupid now.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: it was just a quick example ;)

Comment: @mort Don't be afraid of asking. The worst that can happen is that the question is a duplicate: no big deal.

Comment: @mort -- in addition to what egreg says, sometimes duplicates can help others.  not everyone phrases a question (or indeed thinks of it) in the same way, and searching isn't necessarily precise, so a different manner of expression provides more possibilities for something to be found.